# Programming GSM Module to send SMS

Tags: gsm

I would like to use a standalone GSM Module that can interface with other systems like TV, AC, Fridge, etc.. via an SMS or a Call

For example:
1. If the GSM Module is hooked up to a Smoke Sensor, when there is an alert the GSM Module should be able to send as SMS.

I think there needs to a hardware component (that connects to the Smoke Sensor and GSM Module) where I can install program to send a SMS message when there is a signal from Smoke Sensor.

I would like to know on what this hardware component can be, what programming languages can be used and how the hardware component can interface with various devices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get a programmable GSM module is to get a cheap Android smart phone. For connectivity, you will need to build your own solutions unless the sensors already have some interface. You may want to look into Arduino microcontrollers for that. You can interface to the Android device using Wifi, Bluetooth, USB (newer devices support USB host mode, the cheap ones may not) or the audio jack.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution depends on your resources and how many devices you need.

If you have big budget and hardware and software designers, then you could use naked GSM/UMTS module from some m2m module vendor like Cinterion or Telit. And own MCU for controlling it.

But if you need only few devices, then you could use some programmable GSM/UMTS terminal module, which contain all needed stuff: case, sim-holder, antenna connector, some GPIOs and modem.

For example Cinterion TC65T is this kind of terminal module. It can run a java (J2ME) program. Java programs of TC65T have access to GPIOs, which can be connected to smoke sensor for example. Java programs can also send SMS messages.

Answer (score 0):

The Cinterion TC65T terminal was a 2G cellular device with a Java Virtual Machine to allow you to run J2ME 3.2 applications. Now days you could use a Terminal such as the Cinterion EHS6T-USB which is a 2G and 3G device with Java.

You might find it easier to get hold of a Cinterion "concept board" which has a Java enabled 2G and 3G cellular module on there along with an interface for Arduino style shields.

http://www.gemalto.com/m2m/development/cinterion-concept-board

It runs from a USB lead, plugged into you laptop or PC and need no other external power supply for development. I used one of these connected to a battery, and an Arduino relay board plugged in, to be able to switch our Christmas tree lights on and off via SMS.